# PHP trouble using $_POST in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, post, loops, submit

edit - I solved my "add friend" button issue, now I'm trying to get the userid from the loop below. I want to be able to get the userid of the name that the user looks up (the name that gets submitted to findUsers function, $friend). So basically I want to be able to use result['userid'] and be able to submit that into a database.

I commented in the code where I'm having trouble getting the value for the userid to set.

```
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="' . $result['userid'] . '" />
```

Is there a certain way to use hidden inputs, or is the value just not being set correctly?

```
<?php
 include_once 'config.php';

class Friends{

 function addFriend($userId) {
  return $userId; //this is supposed to return the value of the user's id selected in the loop below via the if statements towards the bottom.
}

function findUsers($friend){
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * from users where username='$friend'");
if (mysql_num_rows($search) > 0){
// $this->addFriend($friend);
 $userLocation = mysql_query("select * from userinfo where username='$friend'");
        $locationResult = mysql_fetch_array($userLocation);
        $locationResultArray = $locationResult['userlocation'];
        $locationExplode = explode("~","$locationResultArray");
 if (mysql_num_rows($search)) {
  // Table column names
   echo '<table><tr><td>Username</td><td>Location</td></tr>';
  while($result = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
    echo '<tr>
    <td><a href="profile.php?userid=' . $result['userid'] . '">'.   $result['username'] . '</a></td>
    <td>' . $locationExplode[0] . ', ' . $locationExplode[1] . '</td>
    <td>
    <form method="post" name="friendRequest" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="' . $result['userid'] . '" />
    <input type="submit" name="addFriend" value="Add Friend" />
    </form>
    </td></tr>';
    }

   }
  }
 }
}

$friends = new Friends();
    if (isset($_POST['userId'], $_POST['addFriend'])) {
    echo "friend button pressed"; //this message is displayed
    if ($friends->addFriend($_POST['userId'])) {
            echo "userID set"; //this message is displayed
            echo $_POST['userID']; //this is not displayed
 } else {
 // some error code here
 }
}


// Edit this to test here
// $friends->findUsers('<username>');
?>
```

Comment: For starters, your code is syntactically incorrect, is it even running at all?

Tell us what errors you're getting and then you might get some help.

Comment: I updated the code to include the full thing. I thought the loop was enough, guess not. I hope this makes  it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That way to add friend is incorrect way, because when you click the "Add friend" button, that will send a `$_POST['addFriend']` and then in the loop the check are going to add all users as friend.

The correct code is here:

```
<?php
function addFriend($userId){
  // check is 'userId' exist, if not, then return 0;
}

if (isset($_POST['userId'], $_POST['addFriend'])) {
  if (addFriend($_POST['userId'])) {
    // some display code here
  } else {
    // some error code here
  }
}
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
?>
<tr><td>
<form method="post" name="friendRequest" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<?php echo $result['userid']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="addFriend" value="Add Friend" />
</form>
</td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

---

**EDIT1:**

You can't use the code above into a function. I fixed a lot of bug that I can see in your code, but still look strange.

I don't get what you want to do with your code, but I made this:

```
<?php
function addFriend($userId) {
  return 1; //using 1 for testing purposes
}

function findUsers($friend) {
  $search = mysql_query('SELECT `userid`, `username`, `userlocation` FROM `users` JOIN `userinfo` ON `users`.`username` = `userinfo`.`username` WHERE `user`.`username` = ' . $friend);
  if (mysql_num_rows($search)) {
    // Table column names
    echo '<table><tr><td>Username</td><td>Location</td></tr>';

    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
      $locationExplode = explode('~', $result['userlocation']);
      echo '<tr>
<td><a href="profile.php?userid=' . $result['userid'] . '">'. $result['username'] . '</a></td>
<td>' . $locationExplode[0] . ', ' . $locationExplode[1] . '</td>
<td>
<form method="post" name="friendRequest" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="' . $result['userid'] . '" />
<input type="submit" name="addFriend" value="Add Friend" />
</form>
</td></tr>';
    }
  }
}

if (isset($_POST['userId'], $_POST['addFriend'])) {
  if (addFriend($_POST['userId'])) {
    echo "test"; //I'm simply trying to get the input to work, can't get it to post. Just using this for a test.
  } else {
    // some error code here
  }
}

// Edit this to test here
// findUsers('<username>');
?>
```

---

**EDIT2:**

Well, you just need to put my functions code into the class and then use the other code outside the class, like this:

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';

class Friends{
  function addFriend($userId) {
    return 1; //using 1 for testing purposes
  }

  function findUsers($friend) {
    $search = mysql_query('SELECT `userid`, `username`, `userlocation` FROM `users` JOIN `userinfo` ON `users`.`username` = `userinfo`.`username` WHERE `user`.`username` = ' . $friend);
    if (mysql_num_rows($search)) {
      // Table column names
      echo '<table><tr><td>Username</td><td>Location</td></tr>';

      while($result = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
        $locationExplode = explode('~', $result['userlocation']);
        echo '<tr>
<td><a href="profile.php?userid=' . $result['userid'] . '">'. $result['username'] . '</a></td>
<td>' . $locationExplode[0] . ', ' . $locationExplode[1] . '</td>
<td>
<form method="post" name="friendRequest" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="' . $result['userid'] . '" />
<input type="submit" name="addFriend" value="Add Friend" />
</form>
</td></tr>';
      }
    }
  }
}

$friends = new Friends();
if (isset($_POST['userId'], $_POST['addFriend'])) {
  if ($friends->addFriend($_POST['userId'])) {
    echo "test";
  } else {
    // some error code here
  }
}

// Edit this to test here
// $friends->findUsers('<username>');
?>
```

---

**EDIT3:**

That's because the function `addFriend` is incorrect... You need to pass the user ID value as argument and then display it like this:

```
function addFriend($userId) {
  return $userId; //this is supposed to return the value of the user's id selected in the loop below via the if statements towards the bottom.
}
```

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I updated my code above. Do you have any recommendations or see any major errors?

Comment: Thanks again for the help. The whole point of the findUsers function is to allow the user to search for other users. The search returns the username (linked to their profile), location, and an "add friend" button. When the users presses add friend, it adds them as a friend. I haven't written the code to actually add them as friends because I haven't been able to get it to post properly. I wanted to solve the posting issue first

Comment: Ok, sorry, there was a bug in my MySQL sentence, I fixed it and updated the answer.

Comment: I'm really not on top of my game. I didn't copy the entire code I had. This is part of a class, and I need to keep that class because the functions are initiated by the search starting (which is submitted on a different form). I updated my code above

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it works now. I was having one of those days yesterday. It makes complete sense now, not quite sure what I was thinking yesterday.

Comment: @user No problem, because is good to learn from mistakes, that way we can understand better the reason of the error.

Comment: I was able to get text to display by pressing the "add friend" button, however I can't get the value for the hidden form (specifically result['userid'] to set properly. I updated my code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. I'm new to PHP, so I'm sorry for the seemingly basic questions!